# React focus on child component input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I currently implement Redux-Form in order to add InputFields to my application. Is there are way to manually focus on an input of a child component?

Code for adding child component:

```
<Field name="Quantity" ref="quantity" onKeyPress={(event) => this.handleKeyPress('inventory', event)} component={ InputField }/>
```

Code for child component:

```
render() {
    const { input } = this.props;
    const inputClass = classNames({ 'parsley-error': this.props.meta.touched && this.props.meta.error }, 'form-control')
return (
    <div>
        {this.props.meta.touched && this.props.meta.error && <span className="parsley-error-message">{this.props.meta.error}</span>}
        <Input {...input} className={inputClass} onKeyPress={this.props.onKeyPress} standalone type="text" placeholder={this.props.placeholder}/>
    </div>
   )
}
```

Current implementation attempt at focus:

```
handleKeyPress(value, event){
  if(event.charCode == 13){
    this.refs["inventory"].getDOMNode().focus();
  }
}
```

I hard coded to focus inventory just for test purposes

Answer (score 1):

Inside your Input component you should be able to do:

```
`<input type="text" autoFocus />`
```

Note the F has to be capitalized.  I haven't test this on newly generated components but in theory it should work.